# Spring Kafka global transaction ID stays open after program ends

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka

I am creating a Kafka Spring producer under Spring Boot which will send data to Kafka and then write to a database; I want all that work to be in one transaction.  I am new to Kafka and no expert on Spring, and am having some difficulty.  Any pointers much appreciated.

So far my code writes to Kafka successfully in a loop.  I have not yet set up
the DB, but have proceeded to set up global transactioning by adding a transactionIdPrefix to the producerFactory in the configuration:

```
producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("MY_SERVER");
```

and added @Transactional to the method that does the Kafka send.  Eventually I plan to do my DB work in that same method.

Problem: the code runs great the first time.  But if I stop the program, even cleanly, I find that the code hangs the 2nd time I run it as soon as it enters the @Transactional method.  If I comment out the @Transactional, it enters the method but hangs on the kafa template send().

The problem seems to be the transaction ID.  If I change the prefix and rerun, the program runs fine again the first time but hangs when I run it again, until a new prefix is chosen.  Since after a restart the trans ID counter starts at zero, if the trans ID prefix does not change then the same trans ID will be used upon restart.

It seems to me that the original transID is still open on the server, and was never committed.  (I can read the data off the topic using the console-consumer, but that will read uncommitted).  But if that is the case, how do I get spring to commit the trans?  I am thinking my coniguration must be wrong.  Or-- is the issue possibly that trans ID's can never be reused? (In which case, how does one solve that?)

Here is my relevant code.  Config is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MYApplication {

@Autowired
private static ChangeSweeper changeSweeper;


@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory=new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps); 
        producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("MY_SERVER"); 
        return  producerFactory;
}

@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> KafkaTransactionManager() {
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<String, String>((producerFactory()));
}

@Bean(name="kafkaProducerTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaProducerTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

And the method that does the transaction is:

```
@Transactional
public void send( final List<Record> records) {
    logger.debug("sending {} records; batchSize={}; topic={}", records.size(),batchSize,  kafkaTopic);

    // Divide the record set into batches of size batchSize and send each batch with a kafka transaction:
    for (int batchStartIndex = 0; batchStartIndex < records.size(); batchStartIndex += batchSize ) {
        int batchEndIndex=Math.min(records.size()-1, batchStartIndex+batchSize-1);
        List<Record> nextBatch = records.subList(batchStartIndex, batchEndIndex);
        logger.debug("## batch is from " + batchStartIndex + " to " + batchEndIndex);           

        for (Record record : nextBatch) {

            kafkaProducerTemplate.send( kafkaTopic, record.getKey().toString(), record.getData().toString());   
            logger.debug("Sending> " + record);
        }

// I will put the DB writes here


}
```

Comment: > `is the issue possibly that trans ID's can never be reused` - shouldn't be an issue because we call `initTransactions()` - its javadocs say `If the previous instance had failed with a transaction in progress, it will be aborted.` - I will see if I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you have three brokers in your cluster (default requirement)? I get a hang on `initTransactions()` with only one broker and on the server log, I see `Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the transactions state topic (configured via 'transaction.state.log.replication.factor')` - but then your first send wouldn't work.

Comment: I only have one broker-- just developing locally.  As you noted, the sends work fine, one after the other, batch after batch, until I kill the program and restart.  So sends seem to be OK, but transaction seems to be the issue.  Note that I am running for now on Wndows, on which I have noticed other issues.

Comment: See my answer; also see [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/513) where the reporter referenced [apache/kafka#3283](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/3283) about some issues on Windoze.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me no matter how many times I run it (but I have to run 3 broker instances on my local machine because transactions require that by default)...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class So47817034Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47817034Application.class, args).close();
    }

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            foo.send("foo");
            foo.send("bar");
            this.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object> KafkaTransactionManager(KafkaProperties properties) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<Object, Object>(kafkaProducerFactory(properties));
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties properties) {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object>(properties.buildProducerProperties());
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("foo-");
        return factory;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "so47817034")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        this.latch.countDown();
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Autowired
        private KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template;

        @Transactional
        public void send(String go) {
            this.template.send("so47817034", go);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and reply.  I will try something modeled on your code with 1 broker and with three, and let you know what happens.

Comment: I increased the brokers to 3 but my own code continued to hang.  I then ran your code (oddly, the KafkaListener caused a lambda api exception at startup'  I commented  it out and used a console-kafka-consumer to monitor the topic instead).  I ran into my exact same problem with your code: the "foo" appeared but not the "bar", program hung.  running a second time nothing was sent and it hanged on the "foo".  If changed the trans ID it then sent the foo as before but hanged on the bar.  Removing the transactioning fixed it.  I think kafka transactioning in broken on Windows 10.  May try on Unix.

Comment: FWIW, I ran this on Mac OS.